# F#.Data HTML Parser Extracting Strings From Nodes

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am trying to use FSharp.Data's HTML Parser to extract a string List of links from href attributes.

I can get the links printed out to console, however, i'm struggling to get them into a list.

Working snippet of a code which prints the wanted links:

```
let results = HtmlDocument.Load(myUrl)
let links = 
    results.Descendants("td")
    |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.HasClass("pagenav"))
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Elements("a"))
    |> Seq.iter (fun x -> x |> Seq.iter (fun y -> y.AttributeValue("href") |> printf "%A"))
```

How do i store those strings into variable links instead of printing them out?

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the very last line, you end up with a sequence of sequences - for each `td.pagenav` you have a bunch of `<a>`, each of which has a `href`. That's why you have to have two nested `Seq.iter`s - first you iterate over the outer sequence, and on each iteration you iterate over the inner sequence.

To flatten a sequence of sequences, use `Seq.collect`. Further, to convert a sequence to a list, use `Seq.toList` or `List.ofSeq` (they're equivalent):

```
let a = [ [1;2;3];  [4;5;6]  ]
let b = a |> Seq.collect id |> Seq.toList
> val b : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]
```

Applying this to your code:

```
let links = 
    results.Descendants("td")
    |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.HasClass("pagenav"))
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Elements("a"))
    |> Seq.collect (fun x -> x |> Seq.map (fun y -> y.AttributeValue("href")))
    |> Seq.toList
```

Or you could make it a bit cleaner by applying `Seq.collect` at the point where you first encounter a nested sequence:

```
let links = 
    results.Descendants("td")
    |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.HasClass("pagenav"))
    |> Seq.collect (fun x -> x.Elements("a"))
    |> Seq.map (fun y -> y.AttributeValue("href"))
    |> Seq.toList
```

That said, I would rather rewrite this as a list comprehension. Looks even cleaner:

```
let links = [ for td in results.Descendants "td" do
                if td.HasClass "pagenav" then
                  for a in td.Elements "a" ->
                    a.AttributeValue "href"
            ]
```